# Go interface to datastore, two implementations

Tags: go, interface

Please see [this repo](https://github.com/rogierlommers/bookstore). I'm trying to create an interface to a datastore. Reason: I don't want to be dependent on a real postgres db while developing, but I want to use an in-memory-implementation during dev.

This works, as long as I create the instances in my main(). For example: `db := store.NewMemoryDB()` or `db := store.NewDB()`.

But now I want to create an instance based on a boolean. So I created a function [GetDatastore(bool)](https://github.com/rogierlommers/bookstore/blob/master/store/interface.go#L16) in the store package. This works for the postgres implementation, but not for the in-memory. I get the following error: `cannot use NewMemoryDB() (type *MockDB) as type *DB in assignment`. Now I really don't know how to solve this. Can someone please give me a hint? How do I make the in-memory one *DB-compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type of `GetDatastore` is the concrete type `*DB`, and `*MockDB` is not `*DB` which is why you get that error. What you want instead is to return the *interface* type `Datastore`, which both `*DB` and `*MockDB` implement.